# Iphone App - Largest File size you can download without using WiFi?

Tags: iphone, mobile, filesize

If I try to download an app that is lets say 100 MB it will not allow me to do it on my phone. Or if I am not connected to a WiFi.  Does anyone know where they cut that off?  Like at 30 MB or something you have to be connect to WiFi?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did a little looking and it still says 10MB online as far as I can tell, but it seems they may have quietly upped it.

[Here](http://www.tuaw.com/2010/02/18/apple-may-have-upped-its-over-the-air-download-limits-for-app-st/) they show people being given a 20Mb limit. It seems they may have upped it. I will keep looking for official documents.

After continuing to look I have found many more sources backing 20MB. just take a look at google for it. My rep only allows me to post one link.

Answer (score 4):

20 MB is the current limit.

Answer (score 4):

According to Macworld, it was raised to 20MB from 10MB back in February 2010:
http://www.macworld.com/article/146512/2010/02/appstore_limit.html